# offsets mismatch between DLL loaded in the memory and on the HDD

Tags: c++, dll

So basically what im trying to do is to change certain strings within a DLL(runtime), to do so, i've opened the DLL using 'hxd' and located the strings i'd be later on changing, copied the offsets from the beginning of the DLL for each string and saved it.

During runtime, i used LoadLibrary() and retrieved module's information details using GetModuleInformation(). this is to find DLL's absolute starting point in the memory. i calculated the real address of the strings using 'lpBaseOfDll' retrieved by GetModuleInformation() and offsets i earlier found. Since i couldn't accomplish this task successfully, i decided to examine these addresses during runtime and realized there is a 6000~ bytes offsets from what i'd expect to see, i've read that during DLLs loading, windows allocates additional 4Kb for paging and so, but im not sure whether or not this is the case.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: have you look to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization ?

Answer (score 1):

Could be ASLR if it is enabled for your application, but I am not certain if it affects your strings also or just the stack, heap, TIB and so on.

But since you seem to always get the same offset-difference, another thing that immediately comes to my mind is the alignment of sections during loading.

When your program/library is loaded and copied to memory, all the sections will be aligned to a certain boundary - they "expand" if you will. So the copied file in memory effectively becomes larger than the one you have stored on your harddisk. See figure 1 on this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx

Since this is not just an overall file alignment for the entire program/library, but a per-section alignment correction, you'll get different offsets in every section. Your strings are stored in one section, and since the previous sections expanded as described you get your 6000~ difference.

The PE format knows about each sections raw-address (RA) and virtual-address (VA [or RVA for relative-virtual-address]). The RA is the offset in your file (for which your manual calculation works fine), but the VA is the one that is important during runtime. Just as a side note: The section alignment itself is stored in the "Optional Header" of the image (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680339%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

So I'd suggest you find out in which section your strings are stored and either calculate the section offset (the VA at runtime) yourself or parse the PE header and lookup the VA of said section directly. You can then calculate the absolute offset of your string in memory from there (**section base VA** + **string offset relative to section base VA**).

But this is all just assumption, you'd have to check that yourself to be completely sure.